# Microphone ALSA noise

Tags: 10.10, sound, microphone

I've got two microphones. Both work well in Windows. However, in Ubuntu the first one (call it X) works fine, but the second one (call it Y) produces a lot of high-frequency noise.
I know, the best thing to do is to buy a new microphone, but X is really old and the headset is broken, Y is almost new and works fine with Windows.
Is there any way to apply a low-pass filter in ALSA? I've also noticed that the sound is a little bit softened...like telephone quality input.

My soundcard is:
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
i've got a toshiba notebook and I've just tried to edit the alsa config file adding this line:
options snd-hda-intel model=auto

~ UPDATE ~
If I use 
`arecord test.wav -f CD` 
everything works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just solved the problem: it is just a new kernel bug. 
You can solve it by using:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=<your_model_or-audo> position_fix=2
```

In `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

Comment: Thank you very much!!!
I spend two days in internet in searching about **acer aspire one 532h internal microphone noise** (with sound card Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller aka Realtek 272).
This fix my internal mic noises.
**Important**: You need to adjust mic volume with the terminal **alsamixer** tool!!!

Comment: worked for me on acer aspire 3. cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC255

Answer (score 2):

I just had to open

```
alsamixer
```

and go to capture screen [F4]
and set mic boost down, and mic record up.

[image]

Comment: I tried it as well, capture at 100 and both boosts at 0, but for me there was still white noise.

Comment: capture should be at 70.